# Live media streaming involving different kinds of devices

Tags: node.js, media, http-live-streaming

I am working on a project which will involve http live media streaming from a variety of devices like android phones/tablets, iphone, ipad, browser,etc. It will be a 2 way communication for all the devices with multiple devices connected to a conversation. I have implemented it partially i.e. one way by capturing audio from android phone(native app) and streaming to a web browser(HTML5 app) with a PHP server using ffmpeg and cvlc. I wanted to know of the best way to go ahead about it. Like, if there are any standards to be followed. Also what kind of a server should I be using? I don't want to use any streaming servers like Red5. I would like to implement the streaming logic similar to Http LiveStreaming by apple. I have come across MPEG-DASH that seems to be a standard for http streaming. I still have to look deeper into it. I was also thinking of using NodeJS for its popularity with streaming. Another worry was how do I go about capturing of media from devices? As in, should I use the native capability of the devices to convert media into an mp4 or any container that it supports and then stream it to the server or capture audio and images for a particular period of time and then send it to server and create a common output(I am not really sure of this idea). The separate capture is basically for simplifying the process of video streaming from the server end to any device. I was also thinking if I could completely bypass the server in any cases like a phone to phone or phone to tablet connection.

I just wanted to be sure of the things I will be using/implementing so that I wouldn't have to make drastic changes later on. Any help is deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered WebRTC as an option?

Comment: Yes. But as far as I know all the browsers haven't yet implemented it. Please do correct me if I am wrong. Hence I was thinking of developing native applications for android, IOS, etc. Once webRTC is supported, it should be straighforward I suppose.

Comment: You could try creating a native app that supports webRTC.

Comment: @vipw I didn't get you. Did you mean implementing the entire webRTC protocol?

Comment: It was a bit tongue in cheek, but I think you could try deploying chrome/chromium/mozilla browser as the container of your app. Eventually you could phase it out for a native platform browser.

Comment: I am new to mobile development and so I did not understand what it is that you meant by "the browser being the container of my app". Did you mean developing a web app? If so I have already strted developing a web app for desktops and mobiles with opera 12.0+ support (using getusermedia). But it is not ideal. I would want to cover as many users as possible; at least the android and ios.